# How do I find the clickthrough rate using dbplyr in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sqlite

Here is the given code:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
sqcon<-dbConnect(dbDriver("SQLite"), "data/sqlite.db")
events <- read_csv("events_log.csv")
sqevents <- copy_to(sqcon, events)
sqevents
```

The sqevents dataframe is like this:

```
## # Source:   table<events> [?? x 9]
## # Database: sqlite 3.35.5 [C:\Users\James\Documents\Work\2021 Sem2\Stats
## #   369\lab4\Data\sqlite.db]
##    uuid         timestamp session_id  group action   checkin page_id   n_results
##    <chr>            <dbl> <chr>       <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
##  1 00000736167~   2.02e13 78245c2c3f~ b     searchR~      NA cbeb66d1~         5
##  2 00000c69fe3~   2.02e13 c559c3be98~ a     searchR~      NA eb658e87~        10
##  3 00003bfdab7~   2.02e13 760bf89817~ a     checkin       30 f99a9fc1~        NA
##  4 0000465cd7c~   2.02e13 fb905603d3~ a     checkin       60 e5626962~        NA
##  5 000050cbb4e~   2.02e13 c2bf5e5172~ a     checkin       30 787dd6a4~        NA
##  6 0000a6af2ba~   2.02e13 f6840a9614~ a     checkin      180 6fb7b9ea~        NA
##  7 0000cd61e11~   2.02e13 51f4d3b6a8~ a     checkin      240 8ad97e7c~        NA
##  8 000104fe220~   2.02e13 485eabe537~ b     searchR~      NA 4da9a642~        15
##  9 00012e37b74~   2.02e13 91174a537d~ a     checkin      180 dfdff179~        NA
## 10 000145fbe69~   2.02e13 a795756dba~ b     checkin      150 ec0bad00~        NA
## # ... with more rows, and 1 more variable: result_position <dbl>
```

I want to find the clickthrough rate which is the proportion of session_id that have action=="visitPage"

My current code is this:

```
sqevents %>% group_by(session_id) %>% 
summarise(clickthrough = sum(action=="visitPage")) %>% filter(clickthrough=="0") %>% collect()
```

However this doesn't return anything:

```
## # A tibble: 0 x 2
## # ... with 2 variables: session_id <chr>, clickthrough <lgl>
```

What did I do wrong? And how do I fix this?

Comment: I have collect() in my code but it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, we may need to unquote the `"0"` as the previous step with `sum` returns a `numeric` summarised output.  Also, if there are `NA` elements, specify the `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum` or else any missing value in the column returns the `sum` as `NA` as `na.rm = FALSE` by default.

```
library(dplyr)
sqevents %>% 
    group_by(session_id) %>% 
    summarise(clickthrough = sum(action=="visitPage", na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    filter(clickthrough == 0) %>%
     collect()
```

Also, other case would be that there is at least one 'visitPage' for each 'session_id', thus the `filter` steps returns 0 rows

Comment: BRO you are fabulous. I did this with an csv file alone a while back with similar code but with "0". Seems like without the "" worked. Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 0):

From you description "[...] which is the proportion of session_id that have action=="visitPage" [...]" you might commit an error further down the pipe using sum(). A nice way to calculate the proportion you described can be this:

```
library(dplyr)

sqevents %>%
    dplyr::group_by(session_id) %>%
    # check if a session has at least one "visitPage" (true or false = 1 or 0)
    dplyr::summarise(yn = any(action == "visitPage")) %>%
    # build a mean from that to get the proportion
    dplyr::summarise(prop = mean(yn))
    # and collect if you like
```